# Intersections where streets have different names

Tags: overpass-api

In Overpass Turbo, I want to find all intersections where the intersecting streets have different names.

I imagine the query would be based on this---

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
way[highway][highway!~"^(footway|path)$"]->.a;
way[highway][highway!~"^(footway|path)$"]->.b;
node(w.a)(w.b);
out;
```

But I want it to exclude any 'junction' that is merely a single way that has been split up.

Essentially I can't figure out how to query `node(w.a)(w.b)` where `[name of .a]!=[name of .b]` (sorry for the pseudocode).